# Avoiding globally overloaded new and delete(in one shared library) to be called while calling new from other shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, symbols, visibility

I have overloaded new globally in get_seven.cpp. Also, I am using -fvisibility=hidden option, but still If I do new from get_seven.cpp, my new is called. I do not want that. How can I achieve that provided

1. I don't want to use statically linked libstdc++
2. Keep overload global only

Is there a way that I can make visibility hidden work through code or some compiler flags.

Command to run: ./demonstrate.sh

**demonstrate.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "Without -fvisibility=hidden:"
make clean && make && ./test
echo
echo "With -fvisibility=hidden:"
make clean && SO_CFLAGS=-fvisibility=hidden make && ./test
#make clean && make && ./test
```

**// get_seven.h**

```
// Returns 7 from PublicGetSeven
#include <cstddef>
//#ifdef __cplusplus
//extern "C" {
//#endif

__attribute__((__visibility__("default"))) int PublicGetSeven();
//__attribute__((__visibility__("hidden"))) void* operator new(size_t nSize);
//#ifdef __cplusplus
//}
//#endif
```

**get_seven.cpp**

```
#include "get_seven.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "malloc.h"
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
int internal_do_calculation();

#pragma GCC visibility pop

#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
__attribute__((__visibility__("hidden"))) void* operator new(size_t nSize) {
    std::cout << "my new called" << std::endl; 
    return malloc(nSize);
}
void operator delete(void* pMem) {
    std::cout << "my delete called" << std::endl; 
    free(pMem);
}

#pragma GCC visibility pop
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)
int PublicGetSeven() {
    return internal_do_calculation();
}

int internal_do_calculation() {
    int* n = new int;    
    return 7;
}
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

**get_three.h**

```
// get_three.h
// Returns 3 from PublicGetThree

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__attribute__((__visibility__("default"))) int PublicGetThree();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**get_three.cpp**

```
#include "get_three.h"

#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
int internal_do_calculation();

int PublicGetThree() {
    return internal_do_calculation();
}

int internal_do_calculation() {
    int* n = new int;    
    return 3;
}
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

**Makefile**

```
CFLAGS+=-g -Wall

UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
    FINAL_EXE_LDFLAGS+=-Wl,-rpath=.
endif

ALL: test

test: test.cpp libget_three.so libget_seven.so
    g++ -g $(CFLAGS) $(FINAL_EXE_LDFLAGS) -lstdc++ -o test test.cpp -L. -lget_three -lget_seven -Wl,-Bsymbolic  
    #g++ -g $(CFLAGS) $(FINAL_EXE_LDFLAGS) -lstdc++ -o test test.cpp -L. -lget_three -lget_seven -Wl,-Bsymbolic -static-libstdc++ 
    #g++ $(CFLAGS) $(FINAL_EXE_LDFLAGS) -o test test.cpp -L. -lget_three -lget_seven #-L./glibc-2.27/bld/ -lc #-lc 
    #g++ $(CFLAGS) $(FINAL_EXE_LDFLAGS) -o test test.cpp -L. -lget_three -lget_seven #-L./glibc-2.36/bld libc.a #-lc 

libget_three.so: get_three.o
    g++ -o libget_three.so -shared get_three.o -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic  
    #g++ -o libget_three.so -shared get_three.o -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic -static-libstdc++ 
get_three.o: get_three.cpp get_three.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SO_CFLAGS) -o get_three.o -c -fPIC get_three.cpp -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic 
    #g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SO_CFLAGS) -o get_three.o -c -fPIC get_three.cpp -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic -static-libstdc++

libget_seven.so: get_seven.o
    g++ -o libget_seven.so -shared get_seven.o -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic 
    #g++ -o libget_seven.so -shared get_seven.o -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic -static-libstdc++
get_seven.o: get_seven.cpp get_seven.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SO_CFLAGS) -o get_seven.o -c -fPIC get_seven.cpp -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic 
    #g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SO_CFLAGS) -o get_seven.o -c -fPIC get_seven.cpp -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic -static-libstdc++

clean:
    rm -f test libget_three.so libget_seven.so *.o
```

**test.cpp**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
    #include "get_three.h"
    #include "get_seven.h"
    
    int main() {
        printf("PublicGetThree returned %d\n", PublicGetThree());
        printf("PublicGetSeven returned %d\n", PublicGetSeven());
    }
```

Comment: @user253751 This is just a sample program, I need all calls in my project to be routed through overloaded version, have to keep global overloading in my particular case

Comment: @niall-douglas Can you please help here

Comment: What exact output are you getting? What output do you want to get?

Comment: @n.m. I am getting following output
my new called
PublicGetThree returned 3
my new called
PublicGetSeven returned 7

Expected:
PublicGetThree returned 3
my new called
PublicGetSeven returned 7

Comment: I am getting the result you expect, not the result you are getting. What does `nm -C libget_three.so | grep operator` show?

Comment: U operator new(unsigned long)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
output is:
my new called
PublicGetThree returned 3
my new called
PublicGetSeven returned 7

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask about libget_seven.so